# Seo friendly URL - .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

In the root folder of my hosting I have an htaccess file with, among other things, the following code which redirect to https and www.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

In the /news/ folder i have entry.php file which have for example ?slug=this-is-first-entry. I want it to look like this `https://www.example.com/news/this-is-first-entry`.

So I want redirect this `https://www.example.com/news/entry.php?slug=this-is-first-entry` to this `https://www.example.com/news/this-is-first-entry`

I have this code in .htaccess in /news/ folder:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ entry.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

It's working fine, but redirecting https and www from root folder does not work. Please help, I am not familiar with htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a THUMB rule. If current directory has a .htaccess with `RewriteEngine ON` then it overrides parent .htaccess directives. If you want parent .htaccess rules to be applied before then use following option:

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
```

Before `RewriteEngine On` line.

So your htaccess file inside /news/ folder will become like:

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ entry.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

---

Additional suggestion: In case you are trying to rewrite non existing files and directories if this is the case then have your htaccess in your news folder like as follows.

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ entry.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Why add this two extra lines? RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d. What do they mean?

Comment: @test, that is checking a condition if a page(uri's part) is non existent then only serve it by entry.php else it will serve even existing pages like js,css etc also with entry.php file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more problem. On `https://www.example.com/news/` I have sorting entries with query string `?category=test` Is it possible with .htaccess to make it nicer for example `https://www.example.com/news/category/test` or `https://www.example.com/news/test`. Although I think the second one would be worse because it would cause confusion with query string slug.